# Missing 'Text Cursor Moved' and 'Scrollbar Adjusted' events in .NET Scintilla component?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, scintilla

Like the RichTextBox, I want to be able to handle events for when the vertical scrollbar has been adjusted (through slider dragging, the mouse wheel or otherwise), and for when the caret / text cursor has been moved. However, these events appear to be missing from Scintilla. How can I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those are available under the UpdateUI event via the UpdateChange structure. Example:

```
    private void scintilla1_UpdateUI(object sender, ScintillaNET.UpdateUIEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Change == ScintillaNET.UpdateChange.VScroll)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```